# VBScript start can take a long time

Tags: vbscript

I'm facing a strange problem and I don't know if it's code or plateform related. I wrote a very simple VBScript to put my computer to hibernate:

```
res=MsgBox("Hbernate ?",1,"Hibernate")
if(res=1) then 
    Dim wshShell
    Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    REM hibernate computer
    strResult = wshShell.Run("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shutdown.exe /h")

end if
```

Sometimes it may take up to 10 seconds to display the message box, sometimes it starts instantly.

My (quite old) PC (Win 8.1 x64) runs smoothly with all other programs I'm using, do you know what can cause this or how can I troubleshout this problem?

Comment: Do you get the same problem when you run a script containing simply `MsgBox "Hello world!"`? (If so, then let's focus on that; why confuse the issue with all that the hibernation stuff?) For guidance, see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, the fact is I don't know if it's related to the hibernation part. I'll check it out to see if it's just VBScript taht take long to initiate or if the code inside the vbs file matter.